# Django filter request result

Tags: django, filter, request

I have two models Player and Game

```
class Player(models.Model):
    userId = models.CharField(max_length = 150, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    playedGames = models.IntegerField()
```

```
class Game(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    award = models.IntegerField()
```

And request that returns winners list.

```
wins = Player.objects.annotate(
    max_award=Max('game__award')
).filter(
    game__award=F('max_award')
).annotate(
    date=F('game__date')
    award=F('game__award')
).values(
    'userId',
    'date',
    'award'
).order_by('-max_award')
```

But there is one bug. If player have 2 or more of the same max Awards with different dates, then in result we get the same number of records (one for each date). 
For example:

- Alex, 75, 2020-05-29
- Alex, 75, 2020-04-23
- Richard, 68, 2020-05-27

But I'd like to get list, like this:

- Alex, 75, 2020-05-29
- Richard, 68, 2020-05-27

How can I get just one record for each user with his max award (with last date)?

Answer (score 0):

- use [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)
- try this..

```
wins = Player.objects.annotate(
    max_award=Max('game__award')
).filter(
    game__award=F('max_award')
).annotate(
    date=F('game__date')
    award=F('game__award')
).values(
    'userId',
    'date',
    'award'
).order_by('-max_award').distinct('game__date')
```

Comment: Thank you, Ahshish. I'v got an error "DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend"